# Android-Studio: Trying to pass data between Activities but get an error while trying to run

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new to programming and basicly slasing may way trough code to make it work.
Now i made the following piece of code but it gives an error and im kinda lost on how to solve it.

The idea is that if i click on a button it retreives some text from a text file in the asset folder and pass it to an other Activity to display it there in a textView.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GeneralInformationActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".IndoorMenuActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".OutdoorMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DatabaseMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ToolsMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

IndoorMenuActivity.java

```
public class IndoorMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.testapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_indoor_menu);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button66);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
            String text = "";

            try{
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                text = new String(buffer);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            finish();
        }
    });

    // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
}
```

ViewActivity.java

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(IndoorMenuActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
    textView.setText(message);

 }
}
```

But when i try to run my app i get the following error messages:

> Error running IndoorMenuActivity: The activity must be exported or
>   contain an intent-filter Error:(29, 33) error: no suitable constructor
>   found for Intent(,Class) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; cannot be converted to String)
>   constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; cannot be converted to Context)

And i have no idea about what is going on and how to solve it.

Comment: change to this `String message = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.testapp.MESSAGE");`

Comment: i think you want to pass "text" as string instead of message in putExtra :-  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, text);  and also try using getStringExtra

Comment: I tried these solutions but it still gives me the same errors when i try to build the app.

It snaps to the code 
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
when the error is displayed.

Comment: Replace this line in your code                                                               Intent intent = new Intent(IndoorMenuActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);

Comment: @PravinFofariya Thank you verry much. That solve the error issue.
It opens the viewer but it doesn't pass/show the data so that's the next thing to find out what is going wrong :(

Comment: What is `message` ? You not declare in your activity.

Comment: Check your message result whey you pass from IndoorMenuActivity to ViewActivity it is possible data not get from file..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly, you need to get data in an activity and send it to another activity on an click event and close the current activity.

Please try the below changes and see if it works,

Remove the Intent Filter for the "IndoorMenuActivity" activity in Android Manifest. Like shown below.

```
<activity android:name=".IndoorMenuActivity" >
</activity>
```

And in the IndoorMenuActivity Activity, Please call start Activity only after the button click event is called. Because if you call startActivity() in the onCreate the ViewActivity will be opened before the button click event.

Change the intent declaration like given below.

```
intent = new Intent(IndoorMenuActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
```

Please change the click event like this.

```
  Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

You can declare the intent variable as global.

Please tell me if it works.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me.
That last onClick event is for a different button (btn_exit)
I intended for it to work with button66 in the code.
button66 gets clicked-> gets the text in a string from the asset manager, makes it available for other activities, closes the current activity and opens the new/view activity and shows the data in a textView field in the new activity.

Well thats the idea anyways :)